# how to access a bridged network within a remote host?

Tags: linux, networking, ip-routing

Hypothetical network setup:

```
router
  ip: 192.168.1.1

host 1:
  eth0 ip: 192.168.1.2
  br0: 172.19.0.1

host 2:
   eth0 ip: 192.168.1.3
```

I want to be able to access the 172.19/16 from the host 2. In large or fine strokes, what needs to be done, in order for me to be able to route from the LAN to the bridged network?

Comment: To get from one network to another network, you need a router. A bridged network is a single network, and all devices on that network can communicate with all other devices on the same bridged network, but to get to a different network you must route the traffic.

Comment: I guess what I was hoping to find, is some practical advice, i.e how do I make the network 172.19/16 be routeable from host 2. I understand the theory, but I don't fully grasp the practice